# create array of ubo and present each at a time to its shader

Tags: vertex-shader, vulkan, uniform

i want to create array of ubo object in my cpu update it and then upload it to the gpu in one call like that. (for the example lets say i have only two objects).

```
    std::vector<UniformBufferObject> ubo(m_allObject.size());

    int index = 0;
    for (RenderableObject* rendObj : m_allObject)
    {
        ubo[index].proj = m_camera->getProjection();
        ubo[index].view = m_camera->getView();
        ubo[index].model = rendObj->getTransform().getModel();
        ubo[index].proj[1][1] *= -1;
        index++;
    }

    int size = sizeof(UniformBufferObject) *m_allObject.size();
    void* data;
    m_instance->getLogicalDevice().mapMemory(ykEngine::Buffer::m_uniformBuffer.m_bufferMemory, 0, size , vk::MemoryMapFlags(), &data);
    memcpy(data, ubo.data(), size);
    m_instance->getLogicalDevice().unmapMemory(ykEngine::Buffer::m_uniformBuffer.m_bufferMemory);
```

i created one buffer with the size of two ubo. (the create do work because it do work with ubo in size one).

```
        vk::DeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(UniformBufferObject) * 2;

        createBuffer(logicalDevice, bufferSize, vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eUniformBuffer, vk::MemoryPropertyFlagBits::eHostVisible | vk::MemoryPropertyFlagBits::eHostCoherent, m_uniformBuffer.m_buffer, m_uniformBuffer.m_bufferMemory);
```

and than i put an offset in the descriptor set creation :

```
    vk::DescriptorBufferInfo bufferInfo;
    bufferInfo.buffer = uniformBuffer;
    bufferInfo.offset = offsetForUBO;
    bufferInfo.range = sizeof(UniformBufferObject);
```

the offset is the size of UniformBufferObject * the index of the object.

*every object have is own descriptorsetLayout but the samepipline*

when i try to update the descriptor set i get the error :

[image]

i couldnt find any aligment enum that specify that information.

if anyone know how to do that it will help alot.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i couldnt find any aligment enum that specify that information.

Vulkan is not OpenGL; you don't use enums to query limits. Limits are defined by the `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits` struct, queried via `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties/2KHR`.

The error tells you exactly which limitation you violated: `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment`. Your implementation set this to 0x100, but your provided offset was insufficient for this.

Also, you should not map buffers in the middle of a frame. All mapping in Vulkan is "persistent"; map it *once* and leave it that way until you're ready to delete the memory.

Comment: how can i get this alinment ? its link error with normal method and when i try to use :   auto func = (PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR)vkGetDeviceProcAddr(*this, "vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR");   its not work either .

Comment: @OriYampolsky: Maybe your implementation doesn't support that extension. The core function is named `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties`.

Comment: @OriYampolsky the 2KHR version needs an instance extension "VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2"

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Library/Source%20Files/01%20Instance%20and%20Devices/12%20Getting%20features%20and%20properties%20of%20a%20physical%20device.cpp) for an example.